# How can we make the swagger-js library save web service interface definitions?

Tags: javascript, web-services, swagger

We are writing an Angular web application that uses the swagger-js library (version 2.1.25) to call RESTful web services described with Swagger 2.0.

Each time we call a service, we create a new Swagger client object, so the swagger-js library requests the Swagger interface definition **again** (see pseudo-code of our calls below).  The JSON definitions for our services can be quite large, on the order of 40 to 120 K bytes.  As far as we can tell, we can't reuse the Swagger client objects

Is there a way to get the swagger-js library to cache the Swagger interface definitions for web services, or reuse the client objects, so that we don't waste bandwidth downloading interface definitions **over and over**?

Sample code below to GET data from the serviceURL/foo entry point in a RESTful service.

```
var swagger = new SwaggerClient({
    url: "serviceURL",
    success: () => {
        swagger.foo.fooGet({param1: x, param2: y},
        (results) => {
            if ( /* results good */ ) { /* do things with results */ }
            else { /* report bad results */ }
        }
    }, (errorResponse) => {
        /* alert user that call failed */
    });
});
```

Comment: Bump. I am struggling with this myself. My thought is to use service workers to cache the swagger client.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up keeping long-lived SwaggerClient objects in our Angular application for services that we called frequently.